# How does the SO engine track data changes to all questions, answers, comments, etc. about Unicorns?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, design, architecture

I'm curious how the SO engine actually tracks data changes to questions, answers, etc. about unicorns in order to show what changes have been made.

For example, is it a coded solution/function that is executed during the update calls:

```
var changes = new List<Change>();
if (oldPropertyValue != newPropertyValue) 
{
   changes.Add(new Change(
       PostType.QuestionTitle, 
       oldPropertyValue, 
       newPropertyValue));
}
```

or if there is a more robust plug and play type component that will do all of the tracking for you, etc....

### Obligatory Unicorn Reference that adds no value to this post...

[image]

Comment: Be careful. The last guy who asked that question is still missing.

Comment: @Nick D: lol.... I'm just curious if this is a bunch of ` if(old != new){ changes.Add(old.fieldname, new.value); }` or if there is a cleaner way of going about it...

Comment: @Chester, I'm not a db expert but I assume database triggers are part of the design.

Comment: @Chester: this question has NOTHING to do with unicorns. This is a travesty!!!!!!!!!1111!!!!oneoneonen!!!!!

Comment: @Ether: LOL....

Comment: Okay, now that there are unicorns, I'll upvote you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They store every version in the original markdown, and the latest version is also stored as a converted HTML document for quick display.

When you request a revision history, it loads the various revisions and diffs them, then displays the diff for you.

Comment: is that difference engine something that is rather robust or straightforward?  I think the storing of all revisions is pretty easy...

Comment: There was a blog post on it.... lemme look.

Comment: Huh, can't find the one I was thinking of.  It went on at length about diff strategies and a little bit on what they implemented and why.

Answer (score 2):

It handles it pretty well, don't you agree?

Comment: I do agree... Hence the reason for the question to figure out what I need to look at for implementing elsewhere...